# Get the table row id on click (HTML+JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this  tag:

```
<td align="center">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="DropdownShow(this)" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></button>
      <div id="@TableRowId" class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="#">Show</a>
         <a href="#">Edit</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

and JS function:

```
function DropdownShow(element) {
  var elm = document.getElementById(element.querySelector(".dropdown-content").id);
  elm.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

I want when I click on the image glyphicon at the table, to show the dropdown div tag with the class="dropdown-content". To do that I need the each row ID, and I have it on the variable @TableRowId. How can I do that?

[image: picture]

Comment: The div is the nextSibling of the element, not a child. So you want element.nextSibling instead of element.querySelector.

Comment: `@TableRowId` is not a valid id

Comment: where is your table? where are your rows? We don't see them.

Comment: @Shilly : `nextSibling` may return the textNode immediately after(whitespace)

Comment: @Pranav Yes indeed. Hence make sure your html is correct. Minifying the html source so there are no hidden text nodes worked well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the reference of clicked button so you need to get the element by getting its parent element where parent node can get from [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) property.

```
function DropdownShow(element) {
  var elm = element.parentNode.querySelector('.dropdown-content')
  elm.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

---

**FYI:** If there is no whitespace after the button then you can use [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property to get the element.

```
var elm = element.nextSibling;
```

---

or use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling#Syntax) property to get the element even there is a text node.

```
var elm = element.nextElementSibling;
```

Check [polyfill option for ie8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling#Polyfill_for_Internet_Explorer_8).

Answer (score 2):

I would pass the @TableRowId to the button as a data attribute like this:

```
<td align="center">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <button data-dropdown-content-id="@TableRowId" onclick="DropdownShow(this)" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></button>
      <div id="@TableRowId" class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="#">Show</a>
         <a href="#">Edit</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

And then your javascript would simply be:

```
function DropdownShow(element) {
    var dropDownContentId = element.getAttribute("data-dropdown-content-id");
    var elm = document.getElementById(dropdownContentId);
    elm.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

This would give you the most robust code, because it doesn't depend on the relationships (sibling/parent/child etc) between the two elements.